# Structuring Div's with CSS

Tags: css, html

I am trying to format a list of links with some css, I am having trouble though.

Please look at the image below...

[image]

```
<div class="tag-list">
    <a href="/tag/htaccess" >.htaccess</a>
    <a href="/tag/css-2" >css</a>
    <a href="/tag/database-2" >database</a>
    <a href="/tag/design-pattern">design pattern</a>
    <a href="/tag/mysql" >mysql</a>
    <a href="/tag/pdo" >PDO</a>
    <a href="/tag/php-2">php</a>
    <a href="/tag/server-2">server</a>
    <a href="/tag/web-design">web-design</a>
</div>
```

the code...

```
<style>
.tag-list a {

    color: #FFF; 
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    background:#444;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    font:.8em Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px!important;
    display: block
}
</style>
```

My goal is to get this list of links to LOOK like that except they should only be the width of the text + padding instead of the full width.  I have tried wrapping each link in the div, wrapping the div around the block of links like I have in the code above,  If I wrap EACH link in a seperate div and remove the `display: block` it will show them as the proper width for each link and each on a new line, the only problem with that is that the margin does not work to let me space them out top and bottom.

I'm sure this is a simple fix for someone who knows more about css

[jsbin.com link](http://jsbin.com/ecoxay)

Thanks for any help

Desired end result something like this...
[image]

When adding `float: left; clear: both;` it makes my other divs show up under it like this...[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These easiest thing to do would be at add a `float` property. This essentially *shrink wraps* elements. I've also added a `clear` property to get them to stack.

```
.tag-list a {
    color: #FFF; 
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    background:#444;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    font:.8em Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px!important;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

I believe this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/thnT8/

**Note:** I'd encourage you to utilize better markup, such as an unordered list. Not only it is more semantic, but it would allow better hooks and avoid the use of floats.

#### UPDATE

Per the comments and my note above, here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/84g6Q/1/

Comment: Thanks for the response, you got it the way I am looking for, it has 1 negative affect though, I updated my post with a new image, it makes other divs below end up showing under it.  My list was originally an unordered list but I wasn't able to style it like this with my knowledge

Comment: It's the `clear`. As noted, better markup would allow you to remove the float and avoid this. See update.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It wasn't working for me at first, when I inspect it, it shows that this is over-riding it `ul li.widget ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 0 0 0 3px;
color: #1980AF;
}` so for these 3 items I had to put !important behind them to make it work, do you know if there is a better way to deal with that so I wouldn't have to use !important ? thanks again I will accept your answer, just curious about that last question so I will know in the future

Comment: You're running into a [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) issue. `!important` solves that, but is discouraged. Without knowing your styles I can't provide an answer. However, review the link and I'm sure you'll get it. If not, you can always make another post.

Comment: awesome thanks for that link, thats good stuff to know and changing my class to an id seems to override it all without using !important

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `display: block;` with:

```
float: left;
clear: both;
```

Should work.

Comment: Looks like Jason got there first :P

Comment: +1 for second place and the fact that you could remove `display: block;`. However, I tend to leave them for some reason :)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using floats and clears by making it a list and changing the display of your anchor tags to inline-block: http://jsfiddle.net/hZLzZ/

Answer (score 1):

You set the display to block, that means it will span across it's entire container.
Just remove the display: block, float the elements left, add `clear:both` to get them to stack, and set the right padding to what you want:.

Here it is using your code: http://jsbin.com/ecoxay/2/edit